# Nutch configuration for near real time crawling

Tags: web-crawler, nutch

I have setup Nutch 1.17 to crawl few domains with inlinks only. I also want to visit their home pages after sometime so that if there is any new post (i.e., page), Nutch should crawl it. Is there any such configuration option for this purpose.

What should be the best way to accomplish this at large scale ?

Comment: why tag with 'stormcrawler' and 'nutch2'  a question about nutch 1.17?

Comment: Sir, I was expecting that all these belongs to same category i.e., web crawlers.